# Php and Mysql Login form with only a key

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

I am currently developing a login form which the user will login from to access `dashboard.php`. The problem is that when I add the key to the table in phpmyadmin and then try to login, nothing happens. Same with when I enter it wrong.

My code is as follows:

`config.php`

```
<?php
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'zxcr_sprxadmin');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Z@nico9TJK');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'zxcr_mhqsprx');
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

`dashboard.php`

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
?>
```

MySQL table: [www.prntscr.com/aejxpy](http://www.prntscr.com/aejxpy)

Login Form: [www.prntscr.com/aejxvg](http://www.prntscr.com/aejxvg)

`login.php`: [www.prntscr.com/aejyjb](http://www.prntscr.com/aejyjb)

`session.php`: [www.prntscr.com/aejywn](http://www.prntscr.com/aejywn)

I just have no clue what it could be, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can't you paste your code here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add in your PHP code in your question instead of an screenshot, thanks!

Comment: is this on the internet?

Comment: Not sure if it's related but in login.php you're SELECTing only the "id" column, but then you're trying to access $row["active"]...

Comment: config.php `<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'zxcr_sprxadmin');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Z@nico9TJK');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'zxcr_mhqsprx');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
`

Comment: dashboard.php `<php include('session.php'); ?>`

Comment: login.php `http://pastebin.com/iHGqLS28`

Comment: session.php `http://pastebin.com/hkmsgcWY`

Answer (score 0):

The reason I do not think it is working is because When you are doing headers it must me a capital l like so: `header('Location: stackoverflow.com');`

Mental NOTE: And You should not be setting the users key in there

Comment: @Iuweiqi I was told it does

Comment: *Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive.* ~ http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `exit;` after `header()` to terminate the execution, else your code will continue executing:

```
header('location: stackoverflow.com');
exit;
```